# Object still accessible after std::unique_ptr goes out of scope. Differing runtime behaviours

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, dangling-pointer

The following code passes to the function `modify_entry` a pointer to an object of type `Entry` and inside the body of the function a `unique_ptr` adopts the raw pointer. However, the object to which the pointers point seems to live on after the function returns.

When I compile this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Entry {
    
    Entry(std::string name) : name_(name) { std::cout << "Constructor for " + name_ + '\n'; }
    ~Entry() { std::cout << "Destructor for " + name_ + '\n'; }
    std::string name_;
    
};

void modify_entry(Entry* e_ptr){
    
    std::cout << "Inside modify_entry()\n";
    std::unique_ptr<Entry>{e_ptr}->name_ += " Doe";

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        
    Entry* entry_ptr = new Entry("John");
    modify_entry(entry_ptr);
    std::cout << "Back from modify_entry()\n";
    std::cout << entry_ptr->name_ << '\n';      // <---- line 25
            
    return 0;
    
}
```

with

> clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
>
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
>
> Thread model: posix

It runs without an error and the output is

> Constructor for John
>
> Inside modify_entry()
>
> Destructor for John Doe
>
> Back from modify_entry()
>
> John Doe

[Here](http://ideone.com/05sKGz), however, I get a runtime error because of line 25.

**Q:** Why isn't there a runtime error when I run the executable generated by clang?

I would really appreciate it if someone could clarify the situation. Please note that I am not trying to properly transfer ownership. This *contrived example of bad code* is the byproduct of a debugging process. `make_unique` and move semantics for `unique_ptr` etc are great, but this is not what I am asking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/1782465) and especially the accepted answer to it.

Comment: @Angew Thanks. Of course, I searched for similar questions before I posted mine, but the tags can be misleading sometimes. I see your point, but, unfortunately, I cannot read the accepted answer; it begins with a parable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, the object to which the pointers point seems to live on after the function returns.

The key thing here is "seems to".  Actually, the `Entry`'s lifetime ends at the end of this line:

```
 std::unique_ptr<Entry>{e_ptr}->name_ += " Doe";
```

The `unique_ptr` has taken ownership of the memory, but the temporary `unique_ptr`'s lifetime ends at the end of that statement, so it also deletes the `Entry` that it owns.  Accessing memory that was formerly used by the object is undefined behavior.  That it works on some platforms and not others is just the nature of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

> Q: Why isn't there a runtime error when I run the executable generated by clang?

Because undefined behaviour is undefined. The program tries to access an object after its lifetime is over. C++ defines no behaviour for such programs.

`make_unique` and move semantics for `unique_ptr` etc are great, and things like this are just yet another reason they are what you should be using.

Comment: Agree with this, you can't rely on differences on uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 3):

Because what you are doing is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), when in the `main` function you use a pointer to a destructed object.

The object *is* destructed (deleted), but you still have a pointer to where it *was*, dereferencing this pointer is what leads to the undefined behavior.